# Does require_once opens new Connection?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got an php script that creates a Connection to my MYSQL Database.

```
<?php

$connection = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password', 'table');

if($connection){

    echo "Verbindung Erfolgreich";

}

?>
```

And than I've got other PHP Scripts for my Application. My Question is now, does it everytime opens a new DB Connection for each time i call require_once("dbconnect.php") ? Or does someone know how I can let the Connection open until i close it?

Comment: If you use `require_once("dbconnect.php")` in the PHP script. Then through out the execution of script connection will be open. Until you invoke `mysqli_close($link)`

Comment: First I open the dbconnect.php file with postman than my other php script that takes something out of the db. It doesnt work

Comment: As i said throughout the execution of same script connection will remain open. If you do something with one script than other script has no relation with the previous one. Both are independent of one another. You will be able to use connection if you create connection in one file and then include that file in another one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `require_once("dbconnect.php")` every time the script is executed a connection will open. If you do not want this you can wrap the connection in a function and use that function if you need a database connection.

**dbconnect.php:**

```
function db_connect() {
    $connection = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password', 'table');
    if ($connection->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error ('.$connection->connect_errno.')'.$connection->connect_error);
    }
    return $connection;
}
```

**someotherfile.php:**

```
require_once("dbconnect.php")
$dbconnection = db_connect();
... do something with the connection...
$dbconnection->close();; // close connection
```